# OPENCV cv2.findContours does not work as expected?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying without sucess to detect an crosshair, using opencv version 3.0.0.
I would like some help, so i can solve the issue and move on detecting the center of it.[image to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlwBx.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("cross1.png")
cv2.namedWindow('Original', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Original',img)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,140,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.namedWindow('thresh', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
clone=thresh.copy()
(_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(clone.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print (len(cnts))
cv2.drawContours(clone,cnts , -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.namedWindow('cont', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('cont',clone)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I guess you need one black pixel distance between your crosshair and the image borders.

Comment: @al-eax is correct. Use "copyMakeBorder" to make a single pixel black border, and use a (1,1) offset in findContours to retrieve contours in the original coordinates

Comment: Thanks all for the help. My mistake was try to show an color on a black and white image.